# What are the SIP connection parameters for an ekiga.net account?

Tags: voip, sip, ekiga, linphone, twinkle

I have a SIP account with [ekiga](http://www.ekiga.net/), but cannot find documentation for the connection parameters.  While `Ekiga` mainly works with `twinkle` I'd like to use `linphone`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the ekiga user agent (UA) to register yourself with the ekiga.net sip server, the connection parameters are:

```
registrar: ekiga.net
username: <your username> (the bit before the "@ekiga.net")
password: <your password>
```

If you are using the linphone UA to register yourself with the ekiga.net sip server, the connection parameters are:

```
username: <your username> (the bit before the "@ekiga.net")
password: <your password>
domain: ekiga.net
(the transport MUST be UDP)
```

Note that if you are using the linphone UA (in fact, if you are using almost any UA other than the ekiga UA), the UA MUST be running on a machine with a public ip address. If your sip UA is running on a machine with a private ip address (i.e. if it's behind a standard domestic NAT router) then your UA's registration to the ekiga.net sip server WILL FAIL.

The reason for this failure to register from a private ip address is explained at https://jitsi.org/Documentation/FAQ#ekiga.net:

> "The ekiga.net SIP servers are configured in a way that prevent Jitsi (and many other SIP user agents for that matter) to register with the service. Please use iptel.org or ippi.com instead.
>
> Slightly Longer Answer: The service at ekiga.net is configured to only accept SIP REGISTER requests that contain a public IP address in their Contact header. This means that registration from Jitsi would fail unless you actually have a public IP address. The Ekiga client circumvents this by using STUN to learn the address and port that have been allocated for the current session."

tl;dr: if you want to receive voip calls using the linphone UA and you are, like most people, using a private ip address, sign-up for a free sip address from any one of:

- getonsip.com
- ideasip.com
- iptel.org
- linphone.org
- opensips.com
- sip2sip.info
- sipgate.co.uk