# How do I install sipclients or sip simple?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository, voip, sip

How do I install [sipclients](https://github.com/AGProjects/python-sipsimple)?

> ### SIP SIMPLE Client SDK
>
> Copyright (c) 2008-2016 AG Projects http://ag-projects.com
>
> ### Description
>
> SIP SIMPLE client SDK is a Software Development Kit for easy
>   development of SIP end-points that support rich media like Audio,
>   Video, Instant Messaging, File Transfers, Desktop Sharing and
>   Presence.  Other media types can be easily added by using an
>   extensible high-level API.
>
> The software has undergone in the past years several interoperability
>   tests at SIPIT (http://www.sipit.net) and today is of industry
>   strength quality.
>
> ### Background
>
> SIP stands for 'Sessions Initiation Protocol', an IETF standard
>   described by RFC 3261. SIP is an application-layer control protocol
>   that can establish, modify and terminate multimedia sessions such as
>   Internet telephony calls (VoIP). Media can be added to (and removed
>   from) an existing session.
>
> SIP allows the endpoints to negotiate and combine any type of session
>   they mutually understand like video, instant messaging (IM), file
>   transfer, desktop sharing and provides a generic event notification
>   system with real-time publications and subscriptions about state
>   changes that can be used for asynchronous services like presence,
>   message waiting indicator and busy line appearance.
>
> ### Features
>
> The library has cross platform capabilities on Linux OS, Mac OSX and
>   Microsoft Windows.  The library should work with minimal changes on
>   any platform that supports C and Python development environments.
>
> The SDK is suitable for building end-points like SIP clients or SIP
>   Application Servers.  To see what the SDK is capable of, you can try
>   Blink from http://icanblink.com
>
> General
>
> - Written in Python  * Non-blocking asynchronous engine  * Built-in
>     configuration framework  * TLS Security for signaling (SIP) and media
>     (MSRP, XCAP)  * Support for multiple SIP accounts  * Multiple Media
>     Types per Session (e.g. Video, Audio and IM)  * Failover support for
>     DNS lookups, SIP and MSRP routing  * Implements re-INVITEs for adding
>     and removing media streams  * Automatically handling if IP Address
>     changes  * Audio conference bridge  * Wav player and recorder  *
>     Acoustic Echo Cancelation  * Answering machine  * Wide-band Internet
>     audio codecs: Opus and Speex  * PSTN compatible codecs: G722, G711,
>     iLBC, GSM  * Video codecs: H.264, VP8
>
> Supported media
>
> - Audio and Video (RTP/SRTP/ZRTP)  * Instant Messaging (MSRP and its
>     relay extension)  * File Transfer (MSRP and its relay extension)  *
>     Screen Sharing (VNC over MSRP)
>
> All media types can be combined together in the same SIP session.
>
> ### Normative References
>
> SIP Signaling
>
> - SIP, Session Initiation Protocol (RFC 3261)  * SDP, Session
>     Description Protocol (RFC 4566)  * An Offer/Answer Model with Session
>     Description Protocol (SDP) (RFC 3264)  * Reliability of Provisional
>     Responses in Session Initiation Protocol (RFC 3262)  * HTTP
>     Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication (RFC 2617)  *
>     The Reason Header Field for the Session Initiation Protocol (RFC 3326)
>
>   - The Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) Refer Method (RFC 3515)  * The Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) "Replaces" Header (RFC 3891)  *
>       Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) Call Control - Transfer  (RFC 5589)
>
> Address Resolution
>
> - DNS resolution (RFC 3263)  * Bonjour multicast DNS
>     (draft-lee-sip-dns-sd-uri-03)
>
> NAT Traversal
>
> - SIP Signaling: Symmetric Response Routing Symmetric media (RFC
>     3581)  * RTP media (Audio and Video): ICE, Interactive Connectivity
>     Establishment    (RFC 5245)  * MSRP media (Instant Messaging and File
>     Transfer): MSRP protocol relay    extension (RFC 4976)
>
> Audio and Video
>
> - RTP, A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications (RFC 3550)  *
>     Real Time Control Protocol (RTCP) attribute in Session Description
>     Protocol (SDP) (RFC 3605)  * SRTP, The Secure Real-time Transport
>     Protocol (RFC 3711)  * Generation and parsing of telephone-events
>     payload in both RTP and SDP    (RFC 2833)  * ZRTP: Media Path Key
>     Agreement for Unicast Secure RTP (RFC 6189)
>
> Instant Messaging
>
> - CPIM, Common Presence and Instant Messaging: (RFC 3862)  * Session
>     Initiation Protocol (SIP) Extension for Instant Messaging    (RFC
>     3428)  * MSRP Protocol (RFC 4975)  * Indication of Message Composition
>     for Instant Messaging (RFC 3994)  * Message Summary Event Package (RFC
>     3842)  * File Transfer (RFC 5547)
>
> Screen Sharing
>
> - Variation of draft-garcia-mmusic-sdp-collaboration-00 using RFB
>     over MSRP
>
> Conferencing
>
> - Conference Event Package (RFC 4575)  * A Framework for Conferencing
>     with the Session Initiation Protocol (RFC 4353)  * SIP Call Control -
>     Conferencing for User Agents (RFC 4579)  * MSRP ad-hoc multi-party
>     chat sessions (RFC 7701)
>
> Presence
>
> - SIP Specific Event Notification (RFC 3265)  * SIP Extension for
>     Event State Publication (RFC 3903)   * PIDF: Presence Data Model (RFC
>     3863, RFC 3379, RFC 4479)  * Watcher-info Event Package (RFC 3857, RFC
>     3858)  * Rich Presence Extensions to PIDF (RFC 4480)  * Contact
>     Information Extension to PIDF (RFC 4482)  * User Agent Capability
>     Extension to PIDF (RFC 5196)   * XCAP Protocol (RFC 4825)  * Common
>     Policy (RFC 4745)  * Presence Rules (RFC 5025)  * Resource Lists (RFC
>     4826)  * RLS Services (RFC 4826)  * PIDF manipulation (RFC 4827)  *
>     XCAP Diff (RFC 5874)  * OMA Reference Release Definition for XDM v1.1
>     and Presence SIMPLE v1.1    Implementation Guidelines  * OMA XML 
>     Document Management V1.1
>
> ### Support
>
> The project is developed and supported by AG Projects. The support is
>   provided on a best-effort basis. "best-effort" means that we try to
>   solve the bugs you report or help fix your problems as soon as we can,
>   subject to available resources.
>
> To request support you must use the mailing list available at
>
> http://lists.ag-projects.com/mailman/listinfo/sipbeyondvoip
>
> Patches and bug reports must be submitted by opening a ticket at
>
> http://sipsimpleclient.org/projects/sipsimpleclient/issues
>
> To open ticket please Register first.
>
> ### Acknowledgments
>
> SIP SIMPLE client SDK has been partly funded by the European
>   Commission under grant number FP7-IST-216217.

Comment: Can you please clarify your affiliation status with the service/software mentioned?

Comment: As it stands, I would personally consider this Q&A to be spam, but as you have a record of positive contributions to the site, I'm not flagging it (yet?). If you want this to be a valid question, please remove all the stuff in blockquotes and sum up in two sentences or so what the application is good for, where to find it and how you are affiliated with that project. Everything else that is not relevant to the question ("How do I install it?") should be removed. Thanks.

Comment: it's in relation to this question:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/866453/linphone-could-not-start-tls-transport-on-port-5060-maybe-this-port-is-already     if it matters, change the question to:  what CLI tools for SIP can be installed...

Comment: You have 1 line of question and almost 100 lines of quoted content from the GitHub page (I assume), promoting the product. Please make your question not look like a spammy advertisement.

Comment: there's nothing I could say better than what's in the github page.  correct me if wrong, but is there not mention of answering your own questions?  It took me quite a while to find this tool.  AFAIK it's entirely unique.   SIPSAK is somewhat similar, but has out of date documentation.  This tool is **unique**.  There's nothing else like it.  Not that I know how to use it, but that's a different matter entirely.

Answer (score 4):

As explained [here on Github](https://github.com/AGProjects/python-sipsimple/blob/master/docs/Install.ubuntu):

> #### SIP SIMPLE client SDK installation on Ubuntu
>
> Copyright (c) 2008-2015 AG Projects
>   http://ag-projects.com
>
> Home page: http://sipsimpleclient.org
>
> This document describes the installation procedure on Ubuntu operating
>   systems from the official public repository maintained by AG Projects.
>
> #### Configure Repository
>
> Install the AG Projects Debian software signing key:
>
> ```
> wget http://download.ag-projects.com/agp-debian-gpg.key
> sudo apt-key add agp-debian-gpg.key
> ```
>
> Add the repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`
>
> ```
> echo "deb http://ag-projects.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
> echo "deb-src http://ag-projects.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -c -s) main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
> ```
>
> Update the list of available packages:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Install SIP SIMPLE client SDK:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-sipsimple
> ```
>
> Install the Command Line Clients:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install sipclients
> ```